# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass when calling from another controller

Tags: methods, controller, undefined, each

I'm trying to trigger all the posts in a groups/show view, but I'm getting error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". Anyone could help me, please?

~~sorry for my bad coding behaviors

posts_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    post = Post.create(permitted_params)
    redirect_to post
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.update permitted_params
    redirect_to post
  end

  def destroy
    Post.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  def permitted_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:message)
  end

end
```

groups_controller:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  end


  def new
    @group = Group.new
  end

  def create
    group = Group.create(permitted_params)
    redirect_to group
  end

    def permitted_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

groups/show.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
<p><i><%= @post.message %></i><p>

  <%= render 'posts/each' %>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p><%= link_to "Powrót", root_path %></p>
  <p><%= link_to "Usuń wiadomość", @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Jesteś pewien?' } %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_each.html.erb:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <ul><i><%= link_to post.message, post %></i></ul></br>
  <% end %>
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users

  root 'posts#index'

  resources :posts
  resources :groups

  get 'posts/each' => 'posts#each'
  get 'posts/group1' => 'posts#group1'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is no @post variable in groups_controller's 'show' action.
may be you need something in show action like:

```
@posts = Post.where(group_id: @group.id)
```

And also when you render a partial from another folder, you have to pass the value of the instance variable (correct me if I am wrong). e.g

```
<%= render 'posts/each', {posts: @posts} %>
```

and iterate by 'posts' instead of '@posts'

Comment: I assume that: 
post belongs to group
and 
group has many posts

Answer (score 0):

in groups_controller.rb

```
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @posts = Post.where(group_id: @group_id)
end
```

in groups/show.html.erb

```
<div class="container">

  <%= render 'posts/each', {posts: @posts} %>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <p><%= link_to "Powrót", root_path %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Usuń wiadomość", @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm:'Jesteś pewien?' } %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

in posts/_each.html.erb

```
<% posts.each do |post| %>
  <ul><i><%= link_to post.message, post %></i></ul></br>
<% end %>
```